# Understanding of quantile plot versus remove outliers plot

Tags: sampling, outliers, quantiles

I have sample `height` for some people sample with a quantile plot like this:

> I need to check that the sample belongs to normal distribution.

[image]

I remove outliers

```
Q <- quantile(people$height, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = FALSE)
iqr <- IQR(people$height)
eliminated <- subset(people, people$height > (Q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & people$height < (Q[2]+1.5*iqr))
```

Results is:

[image]

According to https://data.library.virginia.edu/understanding-q-q-plots/
Is correct thinking that my sample belongs to the normal distribution? Why?

Comment: One can anticipate normal QQ plots not to be exactly linear near the tails. Depending on your purpose, your data may be near enough to normal without removing outliers. I think it is a bad idea automatically to remove outliers just based on the boxplot 1.5 IQR rule. One should remove outliers that can be identified as actual mistakes: For example, if someone's real height is 258 and it got entered as 285.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is useful to have some visual guidance when
trying to judge whether a normal quantile plot is 'near enough'
to linear.

First, here is a demonstration how R makes plots using `qqnorm`.
If the data have $n$ points, then `ppoints` makes a vector
of $n$ points evenly spaced between $0$ and $1.$
Then for the horizontal axis, these points are transformed
by the standard normal quantile function `qnorm`. The vertical
axis shows the $n$ data points sorted in order from smallest
to largest.

In the program below, we simulate $n = 100$ points from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=150, \sigma=9).$ First, we use
`qqnorm` to make a normal QQ plot of the data with
the default open circles as plotting points. Then,
we use the method described above to put orange points
into the open circles from `qqnorm`. They fit perfectly.

```
# method
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(100, 150, 9)
qqnorm(x)
points( qnorm(ppoints(100)), sort(x),  pch=20,col="orange" )
```

[image]

Now, make a normal QQ plot of normal data `x` (left panel below).
Perhaps you think the plot is too 'wobbly' in the tails for
the sample to be normal

We make the same QQ-plot again in the right panel.
As guidance on how well such points should conform to a straight
line, we use the method above overlay QQ-plots (in light blue) from the method above for 20 additional
normal samples with matching means and standard deviations.
Finally, for clarity, we refresh the original probability plot of
the `x`'s.

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
set.seed(509)
 x = rnorm(100, 150, 9)
 qqnorm(x); qqline(x)

 qqnorm(x)         
  for(i in 1:20) {
   y = rnorm(100, mean(x), sd(x))
   points( qnorm(ppoints(100)), sort(y),pch=20, col="skyblue")
  }
  points(qnorm(ppoints(100)), sort(x), pch=19)  # refresh
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

It seems that the QQ-plot of the data `x` is not unusual for normal
samples of size $n = 100.$

Some other statistical software programs give 'confidence bands' around
quantile plots. They seem useful, but I have never understood exactly what the probability 95% refers to. Here is a plot of a normal sample of size 100, made using a recent release of Minitab.

[image]